# Get Facebook Profile Picture of Users Who Liked a URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've gone through as many of the links as I can find here and have yet to find an answer as to whether it is possible to, and how one might go about, getting the profile picture of every facebook user who has liked a 'page' on your website (not a Facebook Page). Otherwise, could this be done with people who like a Facebook Page?

Many thanks for your help,
CW

Answer (score 2):

you can get any user picture by requesting this URL :

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture
```

and you can know who is like your fan page from your friends only by looping throw the **likes** field in their profiles.